# Scheduling a repeating job in Tivoli Workload Scheduler

Tags: tivoli, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I have to create a jobstream with three jobs in it. I want to schedule each job individually.

So say I created a jobstream 'MAINJOBSTREAM_D' in which I have three jobs: 'BEGIN_BATCH', 'MAINJOB' and 'END_BATCH'.

I want BEGIN_BATCH job to start running at 1.00 am.
After BEGIN_BATCH job has completed running, MAINJOB should run in loops with 2mins of interval till 3.00am.
Then once MAINJOB completes I want END_BATCH to run at 4.00am.

Answer (score 1):

The simple definition for your scenario is the following, for performance it's better to set the first AT dependency on the job stream instead of the first job.

```
SCHEDULE MAINJOBSTREAM_D 
AT 0100 
:
BEGIN_BATCH

MAINJOB
 UNTIL 0300 ONUNTIL CANC
 EVERY 0002
 FOLLOWS BEGIN_BATCH

END_BATCH
 AT 0400 
 FOLLOWS MAINJOB
END
```